# load user.mail from Auth0 with async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, auth0, sveltekit

i want load the user.mail from Auth0 and safe there at a const. but I get a arrow. i don't see the error. can somebody help me to find the solution?

```
const userMailInfo = async () => {


 auth0Client = await auth.createClient();

  const result = await auth0Client.getUser().then(user => {
    console.log('mail', user.email);
    user.mail;
  });
  return result;
}

;(async () => {
  const users = await userMailInfo()
  console.log(users)
})()
```

i get follow error:

```
(node:19676) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

Comment: there is no return from the *then callback*. And the code is also incomplete for the error shown here. I think the error occurred somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like these errors are caused by code running on the server-side, where they do not have access to 'document' and the like. In SvelteKit, endpoints always run on the server, and therefore do not have access to all the elements in the 'Client API'.

To guard code from running on the server side, try calling it through `OnMount()`. I've linked a Sapper issue outlining some similar solutions, e.g., using `if(process.browser)`. I am not sure if this works in SvelteKit, but may be worth checking out.

Note: It seems like the error occured outside of the provided code snippet.

---

- SvelteKit Discord Server contains some discussions on the topic, try searching for 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning ReferenceError'.
- (for Sapper) https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/1226